Ansible to change Cisco IOS enable password on multiple devices
Does anynoe know if there is a ansible module for changing the Cisco IOS enable password on devices? There appears to be a user module but that is for usernames only in IOS. Should I use the ios_command module?
This is what i have but I don't think this is the right way to do this...
- name: Set Enable Secret
  no_log: false
  cisco.ios.ios_command:
      commands: 
      - enable algorithm-type scrypt secret thispassword1

Thank you for your help.
